# obtenet campo de informacion en select distinct sum Linq

Tags: c#, linq

tengo una lista de elementos de la siguiente forma

```
    public class MedicamentoDevolverDto
{
    public int IdMedicamento { get; set; }
    public string CodigoMedicamento { get; set; }
    public string Medicamento { get; set; }
    public int StockActualCompartimento { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int DispensadorId { get; set; }
    public int DispensadorBandejaId { get; set; }
    public int DispensadorCajonId { get; set; }
    public int CarroCajonId { get; set; }
    public bool MedicamentoDevolverOK { get; set; }
    public decimal CantidadDevolver { get; set; }
    public bool Devolver { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

el campo cantidad, necesita ser sumado, y debo generar una lista nueva, agrupada por Id de medicamento.
Para esto uso la siguiente sentencia

```
                    var DistinctSumMedicamentos = lstMedicamentosDevolver
                    .GroupBy(l => l.IdMedicamento)
                    .Select(la =>
                        new
                        {
                            MedicamentoId = la.Key,
                            NoArticulos = la.Count(),
                            SumaCantidad = la.Sum(s => s.CantidadDevolver),

                        }).ToList();
```

mi  problema es, que requiero que en esta nueva lista DistinctSumMedicamentos me aparezca tambien el nombre del medicamento (Medicamento).

Busque en el select meter el nombre del medicamento, pero no logro dar con la sentencia que me permite agregarlo.

alguien me puede ayudar con esta duda?
Saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

tienes que agrupar también por el nombre del medicamento. prueba lo siguiente

```
var DistinctSumMedicamentos = lstMedicamentosDevolver
    .GroupBy(l => (l.IdMedicamento, l.Medicamento))
        .Select(la =>
            new
            {
                MedicamentoId = la.Key.IdMedicamento,
                Medicamento = la.Key.Medicamento,
                NoArticulos = la.Count(),
                SumaCantidad = la.Sum(s => s.CantidadDevolver)
             }).ToList();
```