# Error al agrupar por nombre del Mes cuando obtengo valores redondeados en LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Estoy intentando traducir un SQL Query a Lambda, tengo la mayoría traducido pero cuando intento sumar los valores de unos de los campos que intento seleccionar, no los suma. Antes de sumar los valores, les hago un `Math.Round()` para redondear los valores y posterior se debe hacer una suma.
He estado utilizando las siguientes preguntas como referencia pero aun así no suma los valores:

[obtener campo de informacion en select distinct sum Linq](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145065/obtenet-campo-de-informacion-en-select-distinct-sum-linq)

[Sumar columnas con linq](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224592/sumar-columnas-con-linq)

[¿Como sumar/agrupar 2 filas con LinQ en C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303112/como-sumar-agrupar-2-filas-con-linq-en-c)

anexo el query que estoy traduciendo

```
select format(r.date,'MMM') Mes, round(sum(t.payment) / 60,2) [Horas consumidas]
from Requirements inner join Ticket t on r.req_id= t.req_id
where r.id= user and r.id= id2 and r.date between '01-JAN-2021' and '31-MAY-2021'
group by format(r.date,'MMM')

/*
   Resultado esperado

   Mes  HConsumidas
   Apr  0
   Feb  2.75
*/
```

El query anterior agrupa por Fecha pero no exactamente, mas bien obtengo solo el mes de la fecha para poder agruparlo por el mes, asi es como da el `Resultado esperado` pero cuando cuando lo paso a lambda hace todo bien excepto cuando trato de agrupar formateado por mes el campo `date` y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Requerimiento>()
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<Ticket>(), 
    outerKeySelector: r => r.id, 
    innerKeySelector: t => t.id, 
    resultSelector: (r, t) => new CLASS<Requirements, Ticket>(
        Outer = r, 
        Inner = t
    ))
.Where(ti => ti.Outer.id == __user_0 && ti.Outer.id == 2 && ti.Outer.date >= 01/01/2021 12:00:00 AM && ti.Outer.date <= 05/31/2021 12:00:00 AM)
.GroupBy(
    keySelector: ti => Convert.ToDateTime(ti.Outer.date).ToString("MMM"), 
    elementSelector: ti => new { 
        r = ti.Outer, 
        t = ti.Inner
     })' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Convert.ToDateTime' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. 
       Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

Anexo el lambda

```
var HoursByMonth = _db.Requirements.Join(_db.Ticket, r => r.id, t => t.id, (r, t) => new { r, t })
           .Where(temp => temp.r.id == user && temp.r.id == id2 && temp.r.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("01-JAN-2021") && temp.r.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("31-MAY-2021"))
           .GroupBy(temp => Convert.ToDateTime(temp.r.date).ToString("MMM"))
           .Select(g => new { date = g.Key.ToString("MMM"), r = Math.Round(g.Sum(temp => temp.t.payment) / 60, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) });
        return Json(new { hours = HoursByMonth });

/*
   Resultado obtenido

   {date: "Feb", payment: 0.5}
   {date: "Feb", payment: 0.75}
   {date: "Feb", payment: 1.5}
   {date: "Feb", payment: 0}
   {date: "Apr", payment: 0}
*/
```

Hay alguna forma de agruparlo pero SOLAMENTE formateado por mes? es decir `date.ToString("MMM")` en el `GroupBy`?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: A ver dime si esta bien lo que planteo: Primero obtienes la suma completa de todos los registros del campo de interes, despues esa suma la divides entre 60 y despues esa suma dividida entre 60 la redondeo a dos decimales

Comment: 10, 5, 5 ,20, 10, 20. Esos son los valores que tiene cada registro de la columna que vas a sumar, esa suma da 70, despues dividirias 70/60 = 1.16, eso lo que quieres decir?

Comment: @Japv si correcto, el redondeo esta bien, lo que no hace es la suma de los valores, por ejemplo el total de este ejemplo es 2.75 en el mes de febrero y 0 en el mes de abril, al ponerle el `.Sum()` no me regresa lo del query original si no mas bien me regresa los valores separados

Comment: @Japv he editado la pregunta con la verdadera problemática, no estaba viendo el panorama completo

Comment: En Convert.ToDateTime(temp.r.REQ_Fecha) para que  quieres convertir un dato que ya es una fecha.  Utiliza temp.r.REQ_Fecha.Month, pero  como es numerico, crea una tabla de meses  y haces TABLA_MES[ temp.r.REQ_Fecha.Month].